# Nonexistant links under SiteLinks in Google Webmaster Tools

Tags: google, google-search-console, sitelinks

When I used [Google Webmaster Tools](http://www.google.com/webmasters/tools) to check one of my websites, I found that
there are 37 links under site links which do not belong to my websites at all.

The site links should be the inner pages of my website!

I have not used Google Webmaster Tools for half a year and I know these links are hacking results or attempts.

Please tell me how to delete them and how to prevent these types of hacks?

Comment: Want to post a screen shot

Answer (score 1):

I hope by sitelinks, you mean internal links. There is also an option called "Links to your site" which are external links to your site. It would be better if you would clarify.

Moreover, SiteLinks is list of important links in your site. There is an option to demote those links, but as those are links generally form within your site, only way to remove them permanently is to remove those links. But that requires that you have permission to do so.

Comment: Also see here: https://support.google.com/webmasters/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=47334

Comment: yes, SiteLinks is list of important links in my site, as I sid in my question, there are 37 links under sitelinks which do not belong to my websites at all.

Comment: Then what you can do is demote them for the time being. That is the best that could be dont with the Webmaster tools.